# Reading the last 10 months HDFS files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, wildcard

I need to select the HDFS files from the **last 10 months**, based in my HDFS path date:

```
/path/ds=<year-month-day>
```

Is there a way to do that using path wildcards, dynamically, while setting this information on a *.conf* file?

The expected result would be some like (considering today's month):

```
/path/ds=202{1,2}-{03-01}*/hour=*/*/*
```

Comment: Unclear what types of tools you're using. Just hdfs cli? Even if wildcards don't work, you can pipe output of `ls` into `grep` to filter the results

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear. Currently, this information is being set in a .conf file, similar to this (where today I filter by 2021 and 2022):
<path>/ds=202{1,2}/hour=*/*/*
The idea is to filter dynamically the last ten months only, using wildcards, where the result would be something like (considering today's month)
 <path>/ds=202{1,2}-{03-01}*/hour=*/*/*

Comment: With CLI tools, you'd need a script to get 10 months, exactly, to the day. Other solution would be a recursive folder scan with a [`PathFilter`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/PathFilter.html)

Comment: Thank you for you suggestions, I will try one of the alternatives :)